# How to get Rspec test in Colour for windows on MINGW

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3, mingw, ssh-agent

I'm new to Ruby, just tying to learn it, following the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/book)

I'm running the GitBash MINGW for window, and when I run (rspec 2.4.0)

```
rspec spec/
```

I get the response:

```
You must use ANSICON 1.31 or later (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/) to use 
colour on Windows
```

... but I quite like using MINGW. and if I use ANSICON I cant seem to get

```
ssh-add
```

to work, I get the error

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent
```

I could use MINGW for Pushing and ANSICON for Testing, but I'd rather have it all in the one console.

Answer (score 1):

Since GitBash already supports escapes, you should be able to fake RSpec/Ruby by defining the ANSICON environment variable.  Not sure if Ruby actually reads it, but its content is "WxH (wxh)", where W & H are the width & height of the buffer and w & h the window.